# Root finding method

Tags: terminology, newton-raphson

My prof. mentioned a root finding method called something like Alekhine's method or similar, but I can't seem to find anything about it on google, except for some chess variation. Can anyone help out?

Thanks

Comment: Did your professor mention the algorithm or how it works by an chance?

Comment: So it's about multivariate root finding, and we're looking for a curve of solutions. So far I just threw random initial values at the newton solver, and it converges, but in order to get  a higher resolution to the solution, he suggested "alkalines" method, which uses the last solutions and then looks for another from there. A bit like a continuation method.

Comment: Who don't you just ask your professor...?

Comment: hmm I might have found something. I think he meant arc-line method.